# Access point with systemd-networkd

Tags: access-point, modem, systemd-networkd

I'm trying to configure systemd-networkd with wlan1 as access point and wlan0 as client.
However I don't see the hotspot appear.
(I'm using a USB dongle for wlan1)

Here is some of my configurations file :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/systemd/network/08-wlan0.network
[Match]
Name=wlan0
[Network]
LLMNR=no
DNSSEC=no
MulticastDNS=yes
DHCP=yes
DNS=8.8.8.8
```

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/systemd/network/12-wlan1.network
[Match]
Name=wlan1
[Network]
Address=192.168.4.1/24
LLMNR=no
DNSSEC=no
MulticastDNS=yes
# IPMasquerade is doing NAT
IPMasquerade=yes
IPForward=yes
DHCPServer=yes
[DHCPServer]
DNS=84.200.69.80 1.1.1.1
```

Here is the output of some commands :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl status systemd-networkd.service
* systemd-networkd.service - Network Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2023-05-14 22:43:27 CEST; 7min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-networkd.service(8)
 Main PID: 2548 (systemd-network)
   Status: "Processing requests..."
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-networkd.service
           `-2548 /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd

mai 14 22:43:27 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Network Service...
mai 14 22:43:27 raspberrypi systemd-networkd[2548]: br0: netdev ready
mai 14 22:43:27 raspberrypi systemd-networkd[2548]: wlan0: Gained IPv6LL
mai 14 22:43:27 raspberrypi systemd-networkd[2548]: Enumeration completed
mai 14 22:43:27 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Network Service.
mai 14 22:43:27 raspberrypi systemd-networkd[2548]: br0: netdev exists, using existing without changing its parameters
mai 14 22:43:27 raspberrypi systemd-networkd[2548]: wlan1: found matching network '/etc/systemd/network/12-wlan1.network', based on potentially unpredictable ifname
mai 14 22:43:29 raspberrypi systemd-networkd[2548]: wlan0: DHCPv4 address 10.23.161.2/23 via 10.23.160.1
mai 14 22:43:39 raspberrypi systemd-networkd[2548]: wlan0: Configured
```

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 169.254.0.0/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.23.161.2/23 brd 10.23.161.255 scope global dynamic wlan0
       valid_lft 1209092sec preferred_lft 1209092sec
    inet6 fe80::e65f:2de:fe1b:d200/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: wlan1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 90:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ip r
default via 10.23.160.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 10.23.161.2 metric 1024 
10.23.160.0/23 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 10.23.161.2 
10.23.160.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 10.23.161.2 metric 1024 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.0.0 linkdown
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: br0 doesn't work with WiFi devices.

Comment: @Dougie Thank you. I'm simply trying to create an access point with a USB dongle (I don't really need internet connexion because the network will be used to stream video from the pi)

Comment: (I removed the br0 but it doesn't seems to solve my problem)